# Thread-safe vector implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, stl, thread-safety

I'm working on a thread-safe std::vector implementation and the following is a completed preliminary attempt:

```
    #ifndef THREADSAFEVECTOR_H
    #define THREADSAFEVECTOR_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <memory>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <initializer_list>
    #include <functional>
    template <class T, class Alloc=std::allocator<T>>
    class ThreadSafeVector
    {
        private:
            std::vector<T> threadSafeVector;
            std::mutex vectorMutex;

        public:
            /*need to use typename here because std::allocator<T>::size_type, std::allocator<T>::value_type, std::vector<T>::iterator, 
            and std::vector<T>::const_reverse_iterator are 'dependent names' in that because we are working with a templated class, 
            these expressions may depend on types of type template parameters and values of non-template parameters*/

            typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type size_type;

            typedef typename std::vector<T>::value_type value_type;

            typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;

            typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

            typedef typename std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator;

            typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_reverse_iterator const_reverse_iterator;

            typedef typename std::vector<T>::reference reference;

            typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_reference const_reference;

            /*wrappers for three different at() functions*/
            template <class InputIterator>
            void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
            {
                //using a local lock_guard to lock mutex guarantees that the mutex will be unlocked on destruction and in the case of an exception being thrown
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.assign(first, last);
            }

            void assign(size_type n, const value_type& val)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.assign(n, val);
            }

            void assign(std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.assign(il.begin(), il.end());
            }

            /*wrappers for at() functions*/
            reference at(size_type n)
            {
                return threadSafeVector.at(n);
            }

            const_reference at(size_type n) const
            {
                return threadSafeVector.at(n);
            }   

            /*wrappers for back() functions*/
            reference back()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                return threadSafeVector.back();
            }

            const reference back() const
            {
                return threadSafeVector.back();
            }

            /*wrappers for begin() functions*/
            iterator begin()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                return threadSafeVector.begin();
            }

            const iterator begin() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.begin();
            }

            /*wrapper for capacity() fucntion*/
            size_type capacity() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.capacity();
            }

            /*wrapper for cbegin() function*/
            const iterator cbegin()
            {
                return threadSafeVector.cbegin();
            }

            /*wrapper for cend() function*/
            const iterator cend()
            {
                return threadSafeVector.cend();
            }

            /*wrapper for clear() function*/
            void clear()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.clear();
            }

            /*wrapper for crbegin() function*/
            const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.crbegin();
            }

            /*wrapper for crend() function*/
            const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.crend();
            }

            /*wrappers for data() functions*/
            value_type* data()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                return threadSafeVector.data();
            }

            const value_type* data() const noexcept
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                return threadSafeVector.data();
            }

            /*wrapper for emplace() function*/
            template <class... Args>
            void emplace(const iterator position, Args&&... args)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.emplace(position, args...);
            }

            /*wrapper for emplace_back() function*/
            template <class... Args>
            void emplace_back(Args&&... args)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.emplace_back(args...);
            }

            /*wrapper for empty() function*/
            bool empty() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.empty();
            }

            /*wrappers for end() functions*/
            iterator end()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                return threadSafeVector.end();
            }

            const iterator end() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.end();
            }

            /*wrapper functions for erase()*/
            iterator erase(const_iterator position)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.erase(position);
            }

            iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.erase(first, last);
            }

            /*wrapper functions for front()*/
            reference front()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                return threadSafeVector.front();
            }

            const reference front() const
            {
                return threadSafeVector.front();
            }

            /*wrapper function for get_allocator()*/
            value_type get_allocator() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.get_allocator();
            }

            /*wrapper functions for insert*/
            iterator insert(const_iterator position, const value_type& val)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.insert(position, val); 
            }

            iterator insert(const_iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.insert(position, n, val);
            }

            template <class InputIterator>
            iterator insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.insert(position, first, last);
            }

            iterator insert(const_iterator position, value_type&& val)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.insert(position, val);
            }

            iterator insert(const_iterator position, std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.insert(position, il.begin(), il.end());
            }

            /*wrapper function for max_size*/
            size_type max_size() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.max_size();
            }

            /*wrapper functions for operator =*/
            std::vector<T>& operator= (const std::vector<T>& x)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.swap(x);
            }

            std::vector<T>& operator= (std::vector<T>&& x)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector=std::move(x);
            }

            std::vector<T>& operator= (std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.assign(il.begin(), il.end());

                return *this; //is this safe to do?
            }

            /*wrapper functions for operator []*/
            reference operator[] (size_type n)
            {
                return std::ref(n);
            }

            const_reference operator[] (size_type n) const
            {
                return std::cref(n);
            }

            /*wrapper function for pop_back()*/
            void pop_back()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.pop_back();
            }

            /*wrapper functions for push_back*/
            void push_back(const value_type& val)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.push_back(val);
            }

            void push_back(value_type&& val)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.push_back(val);
            }

            /*wrapper functions for rbegin()*/
            reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                return threadSafeVector.rbegin();
            }

            const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.rbegin();
            }

            /*wrapper functions for rend()*/
            reverse_iterator rend() noexcept
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                return threadSafeVector.rend();
            }

            const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.rend();
            }

            /*wrapper function for reserve()*/
            void reserve(size_type n)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.reserve(n);
            }

            /*wrapper functions for resize()*/      
            void resize(size_type n)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.resize(n);
            }

            void resize(size_type n, const value_type& val)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.resize(n, val);
            }

            void shrink_to_fit()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.shrink_to_fit();
            }

            //add function for size
            size_type size() const noexcept
            {
                return threadSafeVector.size();
            }

            /*wrapper function for swap()*/
            void swap(std::vector<T>& x)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                threadSafeVector.swap(x);
            }

            void print()
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> vectorLockGuard(vectorMutex);

                for(const auto & element : threadSafeVector)
                {
                    std::cout << element << std::endl;
                }

                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
    };
    #endif
```

I have based my implementation on the description of the vector class and its member functions found on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and with help from [the implementation of the vector class from the STL](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/vector). Now, a few questions I have about the code I've written so far:

1. When returning iterators, I wasn't sure if I should lock the mutex and then   return the iterator because of the possibility that the validity of the iterator(s) might change due to multiple threads trying to access it, so I went ahead and locked the mutex for all non-const iterators. Is this the right approach?
2. It is my understanding that one should not return pointers from functions when dealing with multithreaded code since this provides a "backdoor" (for lack of a better term) for user code to preform some potentially questionable activity. So, for the implementation of the [assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/), is there another way to write these functions so that it doesn't return *this?
3. I opted to use all local instances of lock_guard instead of having one as a private data member. Would it be better if I had one as a private data member instead?

Many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: [FYI] `*this` does not return a pointer.  It returns what `this` points to.

Comment: As soon as you are returning iterators, the "thread safety" of your class's interface is going to be counter-intuitive at best, broken at worst, because there is no guarantee that whatever the iterators refer to will remain valid.

Comment: (Just to clarify, what happens if one thread starts iterating across the vector in a loop, and in the middle of the loop, another thread writes to the vector?)

Comment: You need to return a thread safe iterator. Merely locking the mutex while you create the iterator is not enough. Returning an iterator is basically like returning a pointer. It gives unsynchronized access to the elements.

Comment: Most of vector's methods make no sense in a multi-threaded environment. For example, how useful is `size()` or `end()` if the vector can change between a call to those members and the moment the result gets used?

Comment: To be honest even if you lock down all the synchronization, this implementation is likely to be the most pessimistic in terms of performance. By that I mean that most real tasks will have much more efficient solutions than a completely synchronized container allows for. In Java they started out with synchronized containers and then decide to unsynchronize them to improve performance.

Comment: A brief history lesson on why Java's Vector class has gone out of vogue may be in order here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: this is not a thread-safe vector in any way, this is just mutex-peppered vector. If providing thread-safe vector was as easy as mutex-peppering al it's methods, one would be part of standard library.

Answer (score 4):

Synchronization between threads is a **global** problem; it can't be solved locally. So the right answer is to unask the question.

This approach is simply the wrong level of granularity. Preventing conflicting simultaneous calls to member functions does not make a container thread-safe in any useful sense; users still have to ensure that **sequences** of operations are thread-safe, and that means holding a lock while a sequence of operations is going on.

For a simple example, consider

```
void swap(vector<int>& v, int idx0, int idx1) {
    int temp = v[idx0];
    v[idx0] = v[idx1];
    v[idx1] = temp;
}
```

Now, what happens if, after copying `v[idx1]` into `v[idx0]`, some other thread comes along and erases all the data in the vector? The assignment to `v[idx1]` writes into random memory. That's not a good thing. To prevent this, user code must ensure that **throughout** the execution of `swap` no other thread is messing with the vector. The implementation of `vector` can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Vector seem inherently not thread safe. That can seem brutal, but the simplest way to synchronize a vector for me is to encapsulate it in another object who is thread safe...

```
struct guardedvector {
   std::mutex guard;
   std::vector myvector;
}

guardedvector v;
v.guard.lock();
... use v.myvector
v.guard.unlock();
```

In win32 you can also use slim reader/writer lock (SRW). They are light and fast mutexes, that can work with multiple readers/one writer. In this case, you replace the guard by a srwlock. The caller code has the responsability to call the correct locking methods. Finally you can template the struct and inline it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a consistent implementation with not too much complication, you need at least two new member functions, for example `disable_write()` and `enable_write()`.

Code which is using your vector can opt if it wants consistent state during some reading code block or not. It will call `disable_write()` at the beginning of read block and call `enable_write()` when it finishes block where consistent vector state was needed.

Add another "write_lock" mutex and in each member function which **makes changes** use this mutex.

While the write lock is active, read operations should be freely permitted so there's no need for "write_lock" mutex for member functions which only read data. Mutex you already have is enough.

Also, you could add another class for write-locking you vector, for example some equivalent of `lock_guard` and even make `disable_write()` and `enable_write()` private and friend with this class, to prevent accidental write lock which is never released.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with myself, the best way to thread safe a vector is to inherit from vector and add a guard.

```
enter code here
template <class t> class guardedvector : public std::vector<t> {
    std::mutex guard;
};

guardedvector v;

v.lock();
//...iterate, add, remove...
v.unlock();
```

You can use a swrlock in place of the mutex. But if you have a lot of threads that read the vector, that can introduce a latency for the writer thread. In certain case you can recreate a custom threading model using just atomics operations with a priority model for the writer, but this require a deep know how the processor work. For simplicity, you can change the priority level of the writer thread.